# Not detecting the text between two characters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to recognize the number between the tags [DN]4[-DN] so I wrote this regex:

```
Regex regexCount = new Regex(@"\[DN]([^)]*)\[-DN]");
Match matchCount = regexCount.Match("[DN]4[-DN]");
```

However when I try to convert the string match to a Int32, I get this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

This is how I tried converting:

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(matchCount.Value);
```

When I debugged, I saw that the matched value returns `{[DN]2[-DN]}` instead of **2**. However the regex101 test gave away the correct result with the same regex: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iK5wO4/1)

What am I doing wrong folks?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently returning the entire match. You need to return the matched context from your capturing group. The [**Groups**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property gets the captured groups within the regular expression.

```
int Count = Convert.ToInt32(matchCount.Groups[1].Value);
```

Also, the negated character class seems incorrect, I would use the regex token `\d` instead.

```
@"\[DN](\d+)\[-DN]"
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that, it worked. Will accept in 5mins